SQL Server: the list of tables in Data Source Manager and Browser does not refresh
Attempts to load the layer from the tables containing geo information fails with error message: invalid layer
In addition, the listing of tables in Data Source Manager doesn't show the primary key which I suspect is related to the problem.
Tried ODBC drivers: 17 and 18
Versions: QGIS 3.34.5 and 3.34.1
